# Inialize object with 0 to multiple objects from another class java

Tags: java, oop, aggregation

I have a Path and a Segment class. A path consists of multiple segments, and the number of segments can vary. When a new Path is initialized I want to be able to add 0 or multiple segments in the path object. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Segment {

  private final double distance;
  private final double duration;

  public Segment(double distance, double duration){
    this.distance = distance;
    this.duration = duration;
  }
}

public class Path {

  public ArrayList<Segment> segments;
  private Segment segment;

  public Path(Segment segment){ 
  // parameter should be able to take in 0-multiple segment-objects
    this.segment = segment;
    this.segments = new ArrayList<Segment>();
  }
}
```

Main method example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Path path1 = new Path(segment1, segment2, segment3);
  Path path2 = new Path(segment4); 
}
```

Comment: you could use `varargs`, a `Collection` or an `Segment[]`. Addtionally it´s unclear to me what you are really asking about here.

Comment: Why cant u pass ArrayList<Segment> to constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Path {
    private final List<Segment> segments;

    public Path(Segment... segs) {
        this.segments = Arrays.asList(segs);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it supplying zero or more segments:

```
Segment seg1 = new Segment(2.0, 3.5);
Segment seg2 = new Segment(1.4, 4.2);

Path example1 = new Path();            // no segments
Path example2 = new Path(seg1);
Path example3 = new Path(seg1, seg2);  // etc.
```